# How do I create a program that auto-deletes files after the folder has reached a certain number of files (deleting old file first)

Tags: windows

I have an access database auto-creating backups to a certain folder. If the backup folder had more than 50 backup files, I want to have the new backup included in the folder while deleting the oldest backup so the folder won't exceed 50 files of backup.

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell something similar to this

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "C:\path\to\folder" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item
```

Then set the script to run daily in task scheduler or similar

[Full example and source on how to create powershell script and schedule](https://pureinfotech.com/delete-files-older-than-days-powershell/)